# Android XML Reading

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I have xml file under res/xml/hi.xml when i use the below code it reads only the id element but i want to read the content of the xml tag not the id value

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) //Keep going until end of xml document
{
  if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
  {
    Log.d("abhayxxxxx", myxml.getName() + "start document reading");
    //Start of XML, can check this with myxml.getName() in Log, see if your xml has read successfully
  }
  else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
  {
    NodeValue = myxml.getName();
    Log.d("abhayxxxx", NodeValue + " node ");
    //Start of a Node
    if (NodeValue.equalsIgnoreCase("author"))
    {
      Log.d("abhayxxxx", "Reading data" + myxml.getAttributeValue(0));
    }
  }
  else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
  {
    //End of document
  }
  else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
  {
    //Any XML text
  }

  try
  {
    eventType = myxml.next();
  }
  catch (XmlPullParserException e)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

here is the xml file's coontent

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <book code="bk101">
        <author id="Gambardella, Matthew">content</author>
    </book>
    <book code="bk102">
        <author id="Ralls, Kim">content</author>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, because I never use XML parsers on android. Try using JSON. It's much easier to use in java based applications. It also has the added benefit of being much smaller and easier to read for humans.

Comment: Unless you're working under some restriction which forbids their use, I highly recommend using an XML serialization/deserialization API like XStream http://xstream.codehaus.org, instead of manually parsing XML.

Comment: Programmer Bruce is correct but I would highly reccomend Simple XML instead: http://simple.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is here in getAttributeValue()  function:

```
if (NodeValue.equalsIgnoreCase("author"))
        {

               Log.d("abhayxxxx","Reading data" + myxml.getAttributeValue(0));

        }
```

As you are using getAttributeValue(0), it will return the value of attribute of a tag, not the node value as you want. To get the node value use `nextText()` function.

Comment: i am new in  stack overflow i cant vote till i have 15 reputations :(